# How to convert a dataframe into a list of sublists based on conditions

Tags: r

I'm working on a web scraping project. I've got to a point where I can fetch the data I want, but I can't convert it in a desired format. Here is example data:

```
search_result <- structure(list(preferred_name = c("CHICAGO NORTHERLY ISLAND, IL", 
                                                   "CHICAGO MIDWAY AP, IL"), lat = c(41.8558, 41.78412), lng = c(-87.6094, 
                                                                                                                 -87.75514), distance = c(7.89027840950889, 17.4390740815157), 
                                GHCNMLT = c("USC00111550", "USW00014819"), WMO = c(NA, "72534014819"
                                )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                ))
```

`search_result` contains name of the stations, latitude, longitude, distance and 2 kinds of station IDs (GHCNMLT, WMO). I want to convert `search_result` data frame into a list; I want to preserve the following: name of the stations, latitude, longitude and distance. Then there is a condition I want to use to create sublists.

For GHCNMLT ID, I want to create a sublist `valid_args_1` that contains the GHCNMLT ID, associated datasets and data types. (assume that GHCNMLT ID exists for all search results.) Then if WMO ID exists, I want to also create a sublist `valid_args_2` that contains the WMO ID, associated datasets and data types. The datasets and data types are fixed per ID type.

```
# valid_args_1 is for GHCNMLT ID and assume all search results have GHCNMLT ID
valid_args_1 = list(
  ID_1 = "USW00014819",
  datasets = c("daily-summaries", "global-summary-of-the-month", "global-summary-of-the-year"),
  data_types = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TAVG")
),

# add valid_args_2 only when WMO ID exists
valid_args_2 = list(
  ID_1 = "72534014819",
  datasets = c("local-climatological-data", "global-hourly"),
  data_types = c("HourlyDryBulbTemperature", "HourlyRelativeHumitidy")
)
```

Eventually I want to convert the search result to a list like this:

```
out <- list(
  # row 1 of the search_result is "station 1"
  station_1 = list(
    name = "CHICAGO NORTHERLY ISLAND, IL",
    lat = 41.9,
    lng = -87.8,
    distance = 7.89,
    valid_args_1 = list(
      ID_1 = "USC00111550",
      datasets = c("daily-summaries", "global-summary-of-the-month", "global-summary-of-the-year"),
      data_types = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TAVG")
    )
  ),
  # row 2 of search_result is "Station 2"
  station_2 = list(
    name = "CHICAGO MIDWAY AP, IL",
    lat = 41.9,
    lng = -87.8,
    distance = 17.4,
    valid_args_1 = list(
      ID_1 = "USW00014819",
      datasets = c("daily-summaries", "global-summary-of-the-month", "global-summary-of-the-year"),
      data_types = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TAVG")
    ),
    # add valid_args_2 only when WMO ID exists
    valid_args_2 = list(
      ID_2 = "72534014819",
      datasets = c("local-climatological-data", "global-hourly"),
      data_types = c("HourlyDryBulbTemperature", "HourlyRelativeHumitidy")
    )
  )
)
```

If I had more than 2 stations, is there a generic way to create such a list? Thank you.

### EDIT

values for `datasets`  and `data_types` for GHCNMLT ID

```
GHCNMLT <- list(
  datasets = c("daily-summaries", "global-summary-of-the-month", "global-summary-of-the-year"),
  data_types = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TAVG")
)
```

values for `datasets` and `data_types` for WMO ID

```
WMO <- list(
  datasets = c("local-climatological-data", "global-hourly"),
  data_types = c("HourlyDryBulbTemperature", "HourlyRelativeHumitidy")
)
```

Comment: You mention other `datasets` (`"daily-summaries"`, `"global-hourly"`, etc.), but what _are_ they exactly?  And what are their corresponding `data_types`, exactly?  The latter look more like (the names of) data _fields_ rather than _types_?  For each station, are you trying to list the (data and) datasets that contain information for that station, along with the "alias" (`USW00014819` versus `72534014819`) by which the station is identified in those datasets?  If you have other datasets, please paste the output from `dput(head(your_dataset, n = 10))`.

Comment: @Greg, I'm going to be using this [API](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation), and the datasets in my list `out` are simply just strings values to be used with the API. The same goes for data types (which really are just fields). I simply want the dataframe `search_result` to look like `out`.

Comment: Yes, but where do those values (for `datasets` and `data_types`) actually _come from_? They do _not_ appear in your sample data for `search_result`.  So we can't simply manipulate the `search_result` dataset to get your desired `out`put...we need to _add_ that information from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the values for `datasets` and `data_types` are what I used to run API queries. For example, https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=TMAX&stations=USW00014819&startDate=2022-05-01&endDate=2022-05-01&units=standard&format=JSON I will modify my questions to specify which `dataset` values and `data_type` values are associated with which IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
dat1 <- list(datasets = c("daily-summaries", 
                   "global-summary-of-the-month", "global-summary-of-the-year"), 
        data_types = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "TAVG"))

dat2 <- list(datasets = c("local-climatological-data", 
                          "global-hourly"), 
             data_types = c("HourlyDryBulbTemperature", 
                "HourlyRelativeHumitidy"))
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)

search_result %>%
  rename(name=preferred_name)%>%
  mutate(valid_args_1 = map(GHCNMLT, ~c(ID_1 = .x, dat1)),
         valid_args_2 = map(WMO, ~if(!is.na(.x))c(ID_2 = .x, dat2)),
         WMO = NULL, GHCNMLT = NULL) %>%
  transpose(str_c('station_', seq(nrow(.)))) %>%
  map(~discard(.x, is.null))
```

Note that We could compare the two structures by `all.equal` but you have different values in your output list as compared to the input list. ie `lat = 41.8558` in the input but `41.9` in the output